# xBox One Streaming not take over console?

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10

Can i stream/play xbox one on my Windows 10 without it taking over the console? Ideally we'd keep watching TV on the xbox one, or watching Netflix, and kids could play on Win10.

Comment: you can use a hdmi cable and plug it into the screen, if the monitor has that capability, so you won't have to worry about conflicts with Win10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you mean by "take over the console" as the console (in my mind anyway) is referring to the large cuboidal brick that is the XBox One itself.

When you stream from your XBox to Windows 10 you basically see (are mirroring) the "display" portion of the XBox on your PC.  You can continue to use your controllers normally, as they are acting directly as input device to the console itself.  If your TV has multiple input sources you can switch to another input and watch (e.g.) Netflix coming from another device while the kids play on the XBox One.   The only restriction that I have found is that somebody has to be signed in to the XBox before you can start streaming.

As an example, our setup has a Blue-Ray player with Netflix and other streaming services on HDMI2 and the XBox One is on HDMI1.  I can stream the XBox to my laptop and see the screen content there while I use the XBox controller to control whatever I am doing.  At the same time my TV can be on HDMI2 and be showing something on Netflix.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reminder. When I posted this I only had the Xbox for media. Since then, I've purchased a smart tv, in which has these other services so this could work now ;)

Comment: @DavidLozzi Ah, glad I was helpful.  I didn't even realize the XBox itself could do stuff like Netflix, as I had the BR player long before the XBox and never had the need to find out if it could do that.